# Visual Studio 2019, C# Instance of a class is returning a null value and I'm not sure why

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, object, orientation

In Visual Studio 2019, C#  instance of a class is returning a null value and I'm not sure why

I'm working on a C# Forms application. An error is occurring where I'm trying to modify/update the values of an existing object using values brought in from text boxes. I'm confident that the data types that are being passed in the constructor are correct.

[image]

[image]

An error message can be seen in the second screenshot:

> Input string was not in correct format

I've pasted in the code for the Holiday object below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AnthonyQuinnAssignmentObjectOrientatedProgram
{
    public class Holiday
    {
        public int HolidayNo { get; set; }
        public string Destination { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
        public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }
        public int NoOfDays { get; set; }
        public int Available { get; set; }

        public Holiday() { }

        public Holiday(int holidayNo,string destination,decimal cost,DateTime departureDate,int noOfDays,int available)
        {
            HolidayNo = holidayNo;
            Destination = destination;
            Cost = cost;
            DepartureDate = departureDate;
            NoOfDays = noOfDays;
            Available = available;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AnthonyQuinnAssignmentObjectOrientatedProgram
{
    public class HolidayDB
    {
        public HolidayDB()
        {
        }

        public static List<Holiday> GetHoliday()
        {
            SqlConnection connection = TravelDB.GetConnection();
            List<Holiday> holidays = new List<Holiday>();

            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                string select = "SELECT *" + " FROM  tblHoliday";

                SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(select, connection);

                SqlDataReader holidayReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (holidayReader.Read())
                {
                    Holiday holiday = new Holiday();

                    holiday.HolidayNo = Convert.ToInt32(holidayReader["HolidayNo"]);
                    holiday.Destination = holidayReader["Destination"].ToString();
                    holiday.Cost = decimal.Parse(holidayReader["Cost"].ToString());
                    holiday.DepartureDate = DateTime.Parse(holidayReader["DepartureDate"].ToString());
                    holiday.NoOfDays = Convert.ToInt32(holidayReader["NoOfDays"]);
                    holiday.Available = Convert.ToInt32(holidayReader["Available"]);

                    holidays.Add(holiday);
                }

                return holidays;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

            return null;
        }

        public static bool UpdateHoliday(Holiday oldHoliday, Holiday newHoliday)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = TravelDB.GetConnection();

            string updateStatment =
                "UPDATE tblHoliday SET " +
                "Destination = @NewDestination, " +
                "Cost = @NewCost" +
                "DepartureDate = @NewDepartureDate" +
                "NoOfDays = @NoOfDays" +
                "Availability = @Availability" +
                "WHERE Destination = @OldDestination" +
                "AND Destination = @OldDestination" +
                "AND Cost = @OldCost" +
                "AND DepartureDate = @OldDepartureDate" +
                "AND NoOfDays = @OldNoOfDays " +
                "AND Availability = @OldAvailability";

            SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateStatment, connection);
            updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewDestination", newHoliday.Destination);
            updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewCost", newHoliday.Cost);
            updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewDepartureDate", newHoliday.DepartureDate);
            updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewNoOfDays", newHoliday.NoOfDays);
            updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewAvailability", newHoliday.Available);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                int count = updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (count > 0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

            return false;
        }

        public static bool AddHoliday(Holiday holiday)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = TravelDB.GetConnection();
            string insertStatment =
                "INSERT tblHoliday" +
                "(HolidayNo,Destination,Cost,DepartureDate,NoOfDays,Available)" +
                "VALUES (@HolidayNo,@Destination,@Cost,@DepartureDate,@NoOfDays,@Available)";

            SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatment, connection);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HolidayNo", holiday.HolidayNo);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", holiday.Destination);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cost", holiday.Cost);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartureDate", holiday.DepartureDate);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoOfDays", holiday.NoOfDays);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Available", holiday.Available);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                int count = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (count > 0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
                // MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        public static bool DeleteHoliday(Holiday holiday)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = TravelDB.GetConnection();
            string deleteStatement =
                "DELETE  FROM tblHoliday" +
                "WHERE HolidayNo = @HolidayNo" +
                "AND Destination = @Destination" +
                "AND Cost = @Cost" +
                "AND DepartureDate = @DepartureDate " +
                "AND NoOfDays = @NoOfDays" +
                "AND Available = @Available";

            SqlCommand deleteCommand = new SqlCommand(deleteStatement, connection);
            deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HolidayNo", holiday.HolidayNo);
            deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", holiday.Destination);
            deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cost", holiday.Cost);
            deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartureDate", holiday.DepartureDate);
            deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoOfDays", holiday.NoOfDays);
            deleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Available", holiday.Available);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                int count = deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (count > 0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the date format in the textbox that is blowing...you could try `DateTime.Parse()` to convert it, or even Better `.TryParse()`. But if you are controlling the input date format then you can use `.ParseExact()`. Line 175 in the screenshot

Comment: When inserting a value into the database, any object that has a value of `null`, needs to use the value `DBNull.Value`. When retrieving data from the database, it's necessary to check if a value is `DBNull.Value` , before attempting to convert it. Also, anything that has a `Dispose()` method, needs to be disposed of.

Comment: Read this, before your next question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here.

First, line 175 is trying to do too much all in one go, including several conversions from string to something else, any of which could result in the exception message you're seeing. Put each type conversion on its own line, and then call the Holiday constructor, passing in the converted value, e.g.

```
var holidayNo = Convert.ToInt32(pCodeUpdate);
var destination = textBoxDestination.Text;
var cost = Decimal.Parse(textBoxCost.Text);
var departureDate = DateTime.Parse(textBoxDepartureDate.Text);
var noOfDays = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxNoOfDays.Text);
var available = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxAvailable.Text);
var newHoliday = new Holiday(holidayNo, destination, cost, departureDate, noOfDays, available);
```

That way it'll be easier to see which conversion is failing.

The second issue is that you appear to be using text boxes to allow the user to enter values which should actually be decimals or dates. If you must use text boxes then give each text box a [Validating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?view=net-5.0) event handler to prevent the user entering invalid values.

Or better still, use a control which is appropriate for the data type being entered, so for integers or decimals, use a [NumericUpDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown), and for dates, use a [MonthCalendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar) or [DateTimePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker)

Comment: Good stuff, thank you. The comments have been very helpful. Separating the conversions on to different lines makes sense in the context of bug tracing. Similarly the use of validating code on the input text boxes makes sense as the input types can be checked at this point. I note   taiwan12   comments and will refer to the guidance before posting. Thanks to all, -Tony